# On-Tick Callback Not Executing in Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, django, websocket

On-Tick callback working in local environment but not executing in Python virtual environment what was the issue.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args: Any, **options: Any):

        api_key = ""
        api_secret = ""
        session_token = ""

        print("Connecting to Breeze")
        breeze = BreezeConnect(api_key="")
        print("WebSocket connected successfully")

        breeze.generate_session(api_secret="", session_token="")

        breeze.ws_connect()
        print("WebSocket connected successfully")
        def on_ticks(ticks):
            print("Ticks: {}".format(ticks))

        breeze.on_ticks = on_ticks

        breeze.subscribe_feeds(exchange_code="NFO", stock_code="ADAENT", product_type="options",
                        expiry_date="28-Dec-2023", strike_price="3000", right="Call",
                        get_exchange_quotes=True, get_market_depth=False)
        
        print("Subscribed to ADAENT options")

        breeze.ws_disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from WebSocket")
```

I have a Django management command located in the management/commands folder. When I run this file using python3 manage.py file_name in my virtual environment, the `on_ticks` callback function is not getting called, and no data is printed. However, the code works fine in my local environment. The virtual environment is active during the file execution, and all required packages are installed. What could be causing the `on_ticks` function not to execute in the virtual environment?

When I run this script in virtual environment the `on_ticks` callback function is called and print the `on_ticks` data.

Comment: Please check the tag descriptions before using them, [tag:breeze] is for a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something on the main thread. If the main thread exits, on some platforms/environments the entire program exits. It can be as simple as adding `inp = input('Press any key to exit')` to the last line of your `main()`